# bash 0 pad numbers on substrings

Tags: bash, substring, pad

I have long lists as follows:

```
D6N
T69TN
K70R
M184V
T215FEG
```

The result must be like this:

```
D006N
T069TN
K070R
M184V
T215FEG
```

I'm new on bash, I tried approaches based in splitting it in columns and reformat. However the positions and length of 2nd and 3rd putative columns are not fixed.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: How do you construct and print your "list"? Where does the "list" come from? Maybe Bash itself isn't the right tool, but awk or sed might be?

Comment: Agreed, bash is a shell, not a data processor, so using other tools like `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, etc is likely going to be nessesary

Comment: @user3829806 Will your lines always be in the format `([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)` and will you always need to pad to the length of the largest number... i.e. the number could be more than 3 digits?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, make all sense. Thank you.

Comment: @edhurtig, indeed the pattern will be always the same. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using awk, using the built-in `match` function:

```
awk 'match($0, /[0-9]+/) { printf "%s%03d%s\n", 
substr($0, 0, RSTART - 1), substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH), substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH) }' file
```

When `match` is successful, it sets two variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`, which can be used to extract substrings. The middle substring is formatted using `%03d`, to pad with leading zeros.

Any lines not matching the pattern won't be printed.

Another option using perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\d{1,3}/sprintf("%03d", $&)/eg' file
```

This replaces any sequence of one to three digits with a zero-padded three digit number. In this version, all lines are printed.

Comment: Oh, I liked the perl one... Clever work with with `/e` :-)

Comment: Indeed, the perl version is working fast and smoothly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is little bit longer with the `sed`'s regular expressions, but here it is in `Perl`:

```
echo "D6N" | perl -pe 's/(\D)(\d)(\D)/${1}0$2$3/g; s/(\D)(\d\d)(\D)/${1}0$2$3/g;'
```

It would pad with zeros 1- and 2-digit numbers surrounded by non-digits. It does it with a simple trick: pad 1-digit numbers with one zero (thus 1-digit numbers become 2-digit numbers), and then pad 2-digit numbers with another zero.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no simple pure-Bash solution for this. Therefore, I'd prefer Perl, because Perl expressions are brief, and Perl is ubiquitous.

```bash
s='D6N
T69TN
K70R
M184V
T215FEG'

echo "$s" | perl -ne '/^(\D*)(\d{1,2})(\D*)$/m and printf "%s%03s%s", $1, $2, $3 or print'
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` based implementation:

```
$ cat testfile
D6N
T69TN
K70R
M184V
T215FEG

$ sed -r 's/[0-9]+/00&/g; s/0?0?([0-9]{3})/\1/g' testfile
D006N
T069TN
K070R
M184V
T215FEG
```

Logic: Unconditionally prefix 2 zeros to numbers & remove leading zeros, till the number is 3 digit long.

Answer (score 0):

This gnu awk can also get the job done:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+' 'RT{print $0 sprintf("%03d", RT); next} 1' ORS= file

D006N
T069TN
K070R
M184V
T215FEG
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bash regexes:

```
#!/bin/bash

re='([[:alpha:]]*)([[:digit:]]*)([[:alpha:]]*)'

while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $re ]]
    printf "%s%03d%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done < infile
```

This matches each line with a regex and captures the three groups: letters, digits, letters. The `printf` format string makes sure that the digit group is zero padded if it is shorter than three digits.